# AMPScript: Only search for part of a string with LookupRows

Tags: email, ampscript, lookup

I'm looking up preferences and adding dynamic content to my emails.
But my preferences are set in our Navision ERP system and one of these preferences contain a special character only used in Denmark: Ø

That preference is "HERRETØJ" but I've found the output from Navision via FTP to Marketing Cloud hard to maintain as UTF8. Sometimes it's registrered as "HERRETÃ˜J", sometimes as "HERRETJ" and sometimes as a third version.

So, I'd like to avoid any unexpected adjustments to that special danish character by searching for the 6 first characters of the preference instead of the full 8 characters.

How should I adjust my code referenced below to search for "HERRET" instead?
Thank you

```
<!--Script Blok--><script runat="server" language="ampscript">
var @id, @c_id
SET @id = [_subscriberkey]

SET @c_id = "not set"

IF  Rowcount(LookupRows("BP_Preferencer", "Subscriber Key",@id,    "Preference","HERRETØJ")) == 1
THEN
  SET @c_id = "587649"
ELSE
  SET @c_id = "000001"
ENDIF
        </script>
%%=v(@c_id)=%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know , there is no AMPScript function read partial cells. To achieve this result, you will have to do the following:

1. Create a new data extension that contains the NAV FTP values and add an empty field for the truncated value.
2. Write a query to copy the contents of the NAV values, and the new truncated value.

   ```
   SELECT *
   ,LEFT ( COLUMN NAME, 6) AS NewColumnYouWillReferenceInLookUp
    FROM [DATA EXTENSION THAT CONTAINS NAV IMPORT]
   ```
3. Replace the value in the lookup formula with the derived truncated result.

Comment: Thanks.
I think we want to do the same thing.
But I'm still not sure how to do it.
How would you do this in the code referenced above?

Comment: Create a query activity to create new data extension with the truncated value.  For the new column `SELECT LEFT ( COLUMN NAME, 6)`.

Comment: Create a new data extension that contains the NAV FTP values and add an empty field for the truncated value. Write a query to copy the contents of the NAV values, and the new truncated value..  For the new column `SELECT  * ,LEFT ( COLUMN NAME, 6) AS NewColumnYouWillReferenceInLookUp`.

Comment: @Data_Kid, you should [edit](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/153818/edit) your comments into your answer.

Comment: @battery.cord my bad will do.